# Trying to import Angularj1.5 component into Angularjs2.0 possible?

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

I am in the middle of migrating from Angular1 to Angular2.

I can easily importing angular2 componets in the angular1 but I am not able to run Angularjs1 components within Angularj2 and getting error message "No Directive annotation found on AngularOneComponet"

From the error message it seems not possible to run angular1 component on angular2 componnet but if anyone knows how to make it work let me know.

```
ComponetA.module

import { AngularOneComponet } from '../common/angularOne.components';

export default angular
  .module('ComponetA')
  .config(componentAConfig)
  .component('angularOneComponent', AngularOneComponet);


ComponetA.component

import { AngularOneComponent } from '../common/angularOne.component';

@Component{{
  selector: 'component-a',
  template: '
    <angular-one-component></angular-one-component>
  ',
  directives: [AngularOneComponent]
})
export class ComponentA{
}
```

Comment: `migrating from Angular2 to Angular1` ?

Comment: oops should be the other way around.